# Using Broadcastreceiver to get network state change

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This is my first time using broadcast-receivers, and i thought it would be a little more straight forward than this. I have a class looking like this:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    boolean isConnected = wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting() || mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting(); 
    if (isConnected) {
        Log.d("Network Available ", "YES" + getResultCode());

    }else{
        Log.d("Network Available ", "NO" + getResultCode());

    }
}
}
```

and i've registered it in my application like this

```
     mReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

And this is working OK, when i shut off my wifi, i get "NO" in log.d.. But how do i get something to "happen"? I want a Return-value or something which i can work with, for example if isConnected is false, then restart activity or something. 
I've googled for days trying to understand what they are and how they work... Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the method is of type `void`, so a return value is out of the question. And besides, the calling class would be `BroadcastManager` or `LocalBroadcastManager`, so you wouldn't have any access to a potential return value.

You *could* register custom listeners inside your `BroadcastReceiver`, but that would mean keeping unnecessary references.

What I would do in your situation is fire off another broadcast with a custom "action" String in the "NO" block:

```
else{
    Log.d("Network Available ", "NO" + getResultCode());
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent(YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION_NAME));
}
```

Register a listener for that event wherever needed and handle the behavior there.